# How to arrange elements vertically?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development and design. How do I make these elements appear AFTER one another ?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset = "UTF-8" />

        <title>
            Title
        </title>

        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "index.css" />

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = "Container">
            <div id = "Declaration">
                <h1>
                    Hi.
                </h1>

                <h2>
                    Bye.
                </h2>
            </div>

            <br />

            <div id = "Skills">
              Some skills
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
div#Container
{
    position: relative;
}

div#Declaration
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    padding-top: 250px;
}

div#Skills
{
    background-color: rgb(72, 141, 200);
}

h1
{
    font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
    font-weight: 500;
}

h2
{
    font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
    font-weight: 300;
}

h3
{
    font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

I'm trying to put the skills container BELOW declaration. But its appearing above ? What's wrong here ?

Comment: don't use absolute positioning.

Comment: Short answer: `display: block`.

Comment: Just a note: If your new to web development, you should learn to use developer tools.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/2nbu7ewo/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code and here is **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/88ogrojy/7/)**

```
div#Container {
    position: relative;
}
div#Declaration {
  //position: absolute;/***Removed**/
    left: 40%;
    padding-top: 250px;
}
div#Skills {
    background-color: rgb(72, 141, 200);
}
h1 {
    font-family:"Gotham Narrow";
    font-weight: 500;
}
h2 {
    font-family:"Gotham Narrow";
    font-weight: 300;
}
h3 {
    font-family:"Gotham Narrow";
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what's happening:

1) Your HTML is correct. But, `#skills` should be below `#declaration`.
2) `#declaration` is set as absolute positioning; That means this container is popped out of the document flow and is hovering over everything. And by everything, it is hovering over `#skills`.
3) Padding-top of `#declaration` is set to 250px; Not only is `#declaration` now hovering over `#skills`, its content is now being pushed down by 250px!

Technically, `#declaration` is hovering over `#skills`. It just looks like declaration is below `#skills` because its content (not its container!) is being pushed down by 250px.

To solve your problem, I would get rid of absolute positioning and instead, set its left-margin to 40%.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using absolute and then relative, if you use absolute you cant make it.
Try This.. Just change your css like this.

```
div#Container
{
    position: relative;
}

div#Declaration
{
    position: relative;
    left: 40%;
    padding-top: 250px;
}
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

The use of positioning isn't necessary here (as long as I understood the layout).

With just this CSS you should be able to achieve what you're looking for:

```
div#Declaration
{
    margin-left: 40%;
    padding-top: 250px;
}
div#Skills
{
    background-color: rgb(72, 141, 200);
}
h1
{
    font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
    font-weight: 500;
}
h2
{
    font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
    font-weight: 300;
}
h3
{
    font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/2nbu7ewo/1/)

[Resource material](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

line to place elements vertically